# Who is "D Castro" and where did his 24 sided unilluminable room really come from?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, research

The [Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IlluminationProblem.html) and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illumination_problem) for the illumination problem both describe a 24-sided room, which they attribute to "D Castro".

Mathworld's citation is simply:

> Castro, D. "Corrections." Quantum 7, 42, Jan. 1997.

This citation has been copied into a few papers and websites. But I can't find any evidence that this paper, the author, or even the journal exists. Where did this polygon really come from?

Comment: I suspect that *Quantum* here is the American version of the Russian magazine *Qvant*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Magazine .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from [the journal cited](http://static.nsta.org/pdfs/QuantumV7N3.pdf):

[image]